# How to get data and error message from Node's fetch API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch, fetch-api

I'm trying to use Node's 18 fetch API to make calls to a REST server.

Here is my code:

```
const get = () => {
    
  let response = await fetch("10.0.0.12/test", {
    method: "GET",
  });

  console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
  console.log(response)

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    let text = await response.text(); << Getting empty text
    console.log("STATUS TEXT: " + text);
    this.data = null;
  } else {
    let data = await response.json();
    console.log("DATA: "); << Getting no data at all
    console.log(data);
    if (res) this.data = data;
  }
};
```

Can't get either status text or data - both are null when parsed....

Output:

```
RESPONSE RECEIVED!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Response {
  [Symbol(realm)]: null,
  [Symbol(state)]: {
    aborted: false,
    rangeRequested: false,
    timingAllowPassed: true,
    requestIncludesCredentials: true,
    type: 'default',
    status: 400,
    timingInfo: {
      startTime: 3119.011163998395,
      redirectStartTime: 0,
      redirectEndTime: 0,
      postRedirectStartTime: 3119.011163998395,
      finalServiceWorkerStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkResponseStartTime: 0,
      finalNetworkRequestStartTime: 0,
      endTime: 0,
      encodedBodySize: 0,
      decodedBodySize: 0,
      finalConnectionTimingInfo: null
    },
    cacheState: '',
    statusText: 'This is a status text message test.',
    headersList: HeadersList {
      [Symbol(headers map)]: [Map],
      [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
    },
    urlList: [ [URL] ],
    body: { stream: undefined }
  },
  [Symbol(headers)]: HeadersList {
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(4) {
      'date' => 'Mon, 03 Oct 2022 18:54:39 GMT',
      'connection' => 'keep-alive',
      'keep-alive' => 'timeout=5',
      'content-length' => '0'
    },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you sure the server sent any response besides the status code? A `content-length` of `0` suggests there is simply no data sent. And if you want to get *"This is a status text message test"* : this is simply `response.statusText`

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: Are you showing us your _actual_ code? The `await` inside the `() => {...}` function gives me a syntax error, because the function lacks the `async` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

try using this pattern and put your code here

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

// async function
const get_geolocation = async () => {
    const url = 'https://geolocation-db.com/json/'
    let res = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET'
    })

    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
}

// call the function
get_geolocation()
```